# How do i create sequence number in order when importing data with one2 many field in openerp7?

Tags: sequence, odoo

I am trying to import data to a form which is apparently the below

- Seq No (sequence number field - am generating with openerp sequence)
- Customer (Customer Reference field)
- Services (one 2 many field)

  - contract Start Date
  - contract End Date

Data i import is something like this

```
Customer    Contract Start Date     Contract End Date

 ABC            13/02/12                12/05/14
                12/05/14                14/04/16
                12/08/16                14/06/18
 XYZ            15/04/12                18/08/14
                11/05/14                19/05/16
```

Now 2 records are generated in my form with sub records, but the id generated for first record is R001 and second is R004. i.e for every record of import an id is generated (but not used). so there's an interval. But this is the method i've identified to import form values with one2many.

Now i need to understand the below

- Am i doing things right, or is there any other way to import one2many
  data
- Is there a way to organize my sequence number while import
- And last one(crooked) is that i can go to database update all values
  to a sequence. And when i create a form field manually the last id+1
  generated by openerp is taken. So i need to update the sequence
  number to start with the last values + 1 that i've changed in the
  database.

Kindly guide me to do the necessary. And feel free to update the post if it's not that clear. Thanks for your time.

From Odony's Comment

My **Register_sequence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data noupdate="1">
        <!-- Sequences for stoc.installed.details (register) -->
        <record id="seq_type_register" model="ir.sequence.type">
            <field name="name">Register</field>
            <field name="code">stock.installed_details</field>
        </record>
        <record id="seq_register" model="ir.sequence">
            <field name="name">Register</field>
            <field name="code">stock.installed_details</field>
            <field name="prefix">Reg</field>
            <field name="padding">3</field>
            <field name="company_id" eval="False"/>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

My **Python file**

```
class installed_details(osv.osv):
_name = "stock.installed_details"
    _description = "Installed Details"  
    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Name', size=64),
        'partner_id': fields.many2one('res.partner', 'Customer', required=True, help="Address of  Hospital / Medical Centre."),
        'product_id': fields.many2one('product.product', 'Product', select=True, domain=[('type', '<>', 'service')], states={'done': [('readonly', True)]}),
'contract_lines' : fields.one2many('contract.contract', 'register_id','Contract'),
    }

   def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
        if vals.get('name', '/') == '/':
            vals['name'] = self.pool.get('ir.sequence').get(cr, uid, 'stock.installed_details') or '/'
        return super(Installed_details, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)
installed_details()

class contract_contract(osv.osv):

    _name = "contract.contract"
    _description = "Contract"
    _columns = {
        'register_id': fields.many2one('stock.installed_details', 'Register'),       
        'contract_start_date': fields.date('Contract Start Date'),
        'contract_end_date': fields.date('Contract End Date')
    }

contract_contract()
```

Comment: It would be useful if you could show the Python definition of your OpenERP model (specifically the `_columns` and the `_defaults`), and the code you use to generate the sequence number "based on an OpenERP sequence". It looks like the sequence consumption is triggered too many times, but this would really depend on where you are calling it.

Comment: Hi Odony, i've updated my question. Please guide me. Thank You.

Comment: Thanks for showing a bit of the code. However I do not see the part where you actually consume the sequence? And in which column you store it... Is it in the `name` of `stock.installed_details`? How do you call `ir_sequence.next_by_code()` or `ir_sequence.get_id()`? If you could show this part of the code it would be easier. Perhaps the problem comes from the sequence type? Have you tried switching it to `no_gap`?

Comment: Hi, Sorry i forgot that part. I've added that now. please check it. and what's that no_gap. Does it have an impact on importing. Bcoz while manually creating records in interface everything works fine. prob is only when importing records (along with one2many records). Thanks a lot for your support.